# Is there a way to use DFS to find the number of nodes in a subtree rooted at u, using a stack data structure and not recursion?

Tags: tree, stack, depth-first-search

I heard that DFS problems can be done using a stack, but I can't seem to think of a way to use a stack to find this.

The recurrence relation is obviously that the number of nodes in a subtree rooted at a node is 1 plus the number of nodes in each of the subtrees of its children.

How can I translate this into using a stack data structure?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In Python it would look like this:

```py
def countNodes(root):
    root.numNodes = 1
    stack = [[root, 0]]  # A stack entry consists of a node paired with a stage
    while stack:
        stack[-1][1] += 1  # Increment stage of stack top (0->1->2->3)
        node, stage = stack[-1]  # Peek stack top 
        
        if stage == 1 and node.left:
            node.left.numNodes = 1
            stack.append([node.left, 0])
        elif stage == 2 and node.right:
            node.right.numNodes = 1
            stack.append([node.right, 0])
        elif stage == 3:
            stack.pop()
            if stack:
                stack[-1][0].numNodes += node.numNodes
```

This will give each node an attribute `numNodes` which will end up getting the number of nodes in its subtree (including itself).

The idea is that each node gets on the stack with a "stage". The stage identifies what we have done with that node:

- Stage 0: nothing yet, first time encounter
- Stage 1: visiting its left subtree
- Stage 2: visiting its right subtree
- Stage 3: all done for this node: it is removed from the stack.

Comment: The answer should be in the form of an array, where A[u] gives the number of nodes in the subtree rooted at u.

Comment: I'll assume that it is ok to store the number of nodes as an attribute of the node. See update to answer.

Comment: Yes, each node is identified by an integer u. Thanks for the update.